# ios sdk version format

Tags: iphone, ios, format, version

Does the iOS version string follow a documented format? I want to parse the sdk version strings and sort them in ascending order. Does the Apple documentation say anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

From [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) NSString *systemVersion
```

An example of the system version is @”1.2”.

```
@propertyic,readonly,retain) NSString *systemName
@propertyic,readonly,retain) NSString *model
```

Possible examples of model strings are **@”iPhone”** and @**”iPod touch”**.

Blog post to access the [UIDevice property](http://servin.com/iphone/uidevice/iPhone-UIDevice.html)