# iOS version vs. iOS sdk

Tags: ios, sdk

Does "iOS version" refer to the version of the language used and also the version of XCode being used?

- ie. Swift 4.2, XCode 10

And is the following example a correct example of "iOS SDK"?

- ie. iOS 12.1

---

I've done a bit of research and taken a look at these links so far but haven't gained clarity yet:

[about iOS target version and SDK version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776313/about-ios-target-version-and-sdk-version)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

[ios sdk version format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033734/ios-sdk-version-format)

---

The reason I'm asking this question is because it is mentioned in the selected answer to this question:

[ios app maximum memory budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887248/ios-app-maximum-memory-budget/15200855#15200855)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IOS version refers to the operating system version on which the app ends up running in each instance (i.e. you could have *m* users on IOS 12 and *n* users on IOS 11 for the same binary).

The SDK version is the version of the set of official development libraries and tools which you use to create an app.  The version number of the SDK tends to be incremented in lock-step with new IOS versions (i.e. to properly target IOS 12 you need version 12 of the SDK, too; but an app written for IOS 11 using version 11 of the SDK will often continue to work fine on IOS 12 as well).

(An earlier version of this answer mentioned XCode as part of the SDK but it isn't strictly, and is currently at version 10.1.)

Comment: So was my understanding simply opposite?

Comment: It would appear that way, but you're probably the best judge of that.

Comment: Well obviously you have a ton more experience than I do so I would have to disagree chief. You would be the best judge of that.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the resources you linked to in your question are somewhat confusing and I'm not entirely sure what your mental concept looks like now. I hope this answer was enough to fix it, but I am by no means convinced. I hope you ask more questions, though Stack Overflow might not be the best place for getting a general overview.